# PHP: Explode comma outside of brackets

Tags: php, arrays, regex, multidimensional-array, explode

Below is a string I've tried to explode only on comma's outside of the first set of brackets.

`Wheat Flour (2%) [Wheat Flour, Wheat Gluten, Calcium Carbonate, Iron, Niacin (B3), Thiamin (B1), Ascorbic Acid], Water, Yeast, Salt, Vegetable Oils (Palm, Rapeseed, oils (sunflower, rapeseed)), Soya Flour`

### 1st Attempt

```
preg_split("/[\[\]|()]+/", "Wheat Flour (2%) [Wheat Flour, Wheat Gluten, Calcium Carbonate, Iron, Niacin (B3), Thiamin (B1), Ascorbic Acid], Water, Yeast, Salt, Vegetable Oils (Palm, Rapeseed, oils (sunflower, rapeseed)), Soya Flour", -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Which returns:

```
[0] => Wheat Flour 
[1] => 2%
[2] => Wheat Flour, Wheat Gluten, Calcium Carbonate, Iron, Niacin 
[3] => B3
[4] => , Thiamin 
[5] => B1
[6] => , Ascorbic Acid
[7] => , Water, Yeast, Salt, Vegetable Oils 
[8] => Palm, Rapeseed
[9] => , Soya Flour
```

### 2nd Attempt

```
preg_split('/\|(?![^(]*\))/', "Wheat Flour (2%) [Wheat Flour, Wheat Gluten, Calcium Carbonate, Iron, Niacin (B3), Thiamin (B1), Ascorbic Acid], Water, Yeast, Salt, Vegetable Oils (Palm, Rapeseed, oils (sunflower, rapeseed)), Soya Flour");
```

Returns:

```
[0] => Wheat Flour (2%) [Wheat Flour, Wheat Gluten, Calcium Carbonate, Iron, Niacin (B3), Thiamin (B1), Ascorbic Acid], Water, Yeast, Salt, Vegetable Oils (Palm, Rapeseed), Soya Flour
```

The first attempt is the closest I've been able to get to the below output I'm trying to get.

```
[0] => "Wheat Flour (2%) [Wheat Flour, Wheat Gluten, Calcium Carbonate, Iron, Niacin (B3), Thiamin (B1), Ascorbic Acid]"
[1] => "Water"
[2] => "Yeast"
[3] => "Salt"
[4] => "Vegetable Oils (Palm, Rapeseed, oils (sunflower, rapeseed))"
[5] => "Soya Flour"
```

Comment: If there is a comma before the first `[...]` substring, would you like to split there?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sorry, pasted wrong output, I've updated the question with the correct output wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this PCRE regex for splitting:

```sh
(?:(\((?:[^()]*|(?-1))*\))|(\[(?:[^][]*|(?-1))*\]))(*SKIP)(*F)|\h*,\h*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BObjYK/1)

**Code:**

```sh
$s = 'Wheat Flour [Wheat Flour, Wheat Gluten, Calcium Carbonate, Iron, Niacin (B3), Thiamin (B1), Ascorbic Acid], Water, Yeast, Salt, Vegetable Oils (Palm, Rapeseed, oils (sunflower, rapeseed)), Soya Flour';
$re = '~(?:(\((?:[^()]*|(?-1))*\))|(\[(?:[^][]*|(?-1))*\]))(*SKIP)(*F)|\h*,\h*~';

print_r(preg_split($re, $s));
```

**Output:**

```sh
Array
(
    [0] => Wheat Flour [Wheat Flour, Wheat Gluten, Calcium Carbonate, Iron, Niacin (B3), Thiamin (B1), Ascorbic Acid]
    [1] => Water
    [2] => Yeast
    [3] => Salt
    [4] => Vegetable Oils (Palm, Rapeseed, oils (sunflower, rapeseed))
    [5] => Soya Flour
)
```

**RegEx Explained:**

- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `(\((?:[^()]*|(?-1))*\))`: Recursive pattern to match a possibly nested `(...)` substring
  - `|`: OR
  - `(\[(?:[^][]*|(?-1))*\])`: Recursive pattern to match a possibly nested `[...]` substring
- `)`:
- `(*SKIP)(*F)`: Skip and Fail this match i.e. retain this data in split result
- `|`: OR
- `\h*,\h*`: Match a comma surrounded with 0 or more whitespaces on either side

Comment: If there was an additional bracket on a line is it easily to handle it, I've updated the initial question, for example [0] => "Wheat Flour (2%) [Wheat Flour, Wheat Gluten, Calcium Carbonate, Iron, Niacin (B3), Thiamin (B1), Ascorbic Acid]", the two brackets can be [] or () but either/or can be first/second in the string?

Comment: My solution works [perfectly fine in the regex demo with your latest updated string](https://regex101.com/r/BObjYK/2)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```php
$text = "Wheat Flour (2%) [Wheat Flour, Wheat Gluten, Calcium Carbonate, Iron, Niacin (B3), Thiamin (B1), Ascorbic Acid], Water, Yeast, Salt, Vegetable Oils (Palm, Rapeseed, oils (sunflower, rapeseed)), Soya Flour"; 
if (preg_match_all('~[^][(),\s][^][(),]*(?:\s*(?:(\[(?:[^][]++|(?1))*])|(\((?:[^()]++|(?2))*\))))*~', $text, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]); 
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y8gKST/3) and the [**PHP demo**](https://3v4l.org/5Gs3J).

*Details*:

- `[^][(),\s]` - a char other than square and round brackets, a comma and whitespace
- `[^][(),]*` - zero or more chars other than square and round brackets and a comma
- `(?:` - a non-capturing group:

  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `(?:`  - either
  - `(\[(?:[^][]++|(?1))*])` - a `[...]` substring with nested `[...]`
  - `|` - or
  - `(\((?:[^()]++|(?2))*\))`  - a `(...)` substring with any nested parentheses inside
- `)*` - an optional sequence, zero or more times.

Comment: If there was an additional bracket on a line is it easily to handle it, I've updated the initial question, for example `[0] => "Wheat Flour (2%) [Wheat Flour, Wheat Gluten, Calcium Carbonate, Iron, Niacin (B3), Thiamin (B1), Ascorbic Acid]"`, the two brackets can be `[]` or `()` but either/or can be first/second in the string?

Comment: @llanato Then use `[^][(),\s][^][(),]*(?:\s*(?:(\[(?:[^][]++|(?1))*])|(\((?:[^()]++|(?2))*\))))*`. See the updated answer.