# PHP: Regex Matching Not Ignoring Second/Thrid Level Closing Brackets

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching, preg-match, brackets

I have a string below, following on from the output of [PHP: Explode comma outside of brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66960242/php-explode-comma-outside-of-brackets/66960540?noredirect=1#comment118371897_66960540).

`Plum and Raspberry Jam (Glucose-Fructose Syrup, Plum Purée, Sugar, Raspberry Puree, Gelling Agent (Pectin), Acid (Citric Acid), Acidity Regulator (Sodium Citrates, Thiamin (B3)), Colour (Anthocyanins), Preservative (Potassium Sorbate), Flavouring) [23%]`

I'm trying to get the `top` level brackets so an output like:

```
[0] => "Plum and Raspberry Jam"
[1] => "Glucose-Fructose Syrup, Plum Purée, Sugar, Raspberry Puree, Gelling Agent (Pectin), Acid (Citric Acid), Acidity Regulator (Sodium Citrates, Thiamin (B3)), Colour (Anthocyanins), Preservative (Potassium Sorbate), Flavouring"
[2] => "23%"
```

The regex I've been using so far and it works in other cases but not here is:

```
preg_match_all('~\((.*?)\)|\[.*?]~', "Plum and Raspberry Jam (Glucose-Fructose Syrup, Plum Purée, Sugar, Raspberry Puree, Gelling Agent (Pectin), Acid (Citric Acid), Acidity Regulator (Sodium Citrates, Thiamin (B3)), Colour (Anthocyanins), Preservative (Potassium Sorbate), Flavouring) [23%]", $matches)
```

As you can see at https://regex101.com/r/RzUs8E/1 it starts matching on the first level bracket but if it finds a second or third level closing bracket it stops here.

I've also tried `\((.*?)\).\[.*?]` but it wont match if the first top level bracket is a `[` instead of `(`.

### Example Data:

- Plum and Raspberry Jam (Glucose-Fructose Syrup, Plum Purée, Sugar, Raspberry Puree, Gelling Agent (Pectin), Acid (Citric Acid), Acidity Regulator (Sodium Citrates, Thiamin (B3)), Colour (Anthocyanins), Preservative (Potassium Sorbate), Flavouring) [23%]
- Plum and Raspberry Jam (Glucose-Fructose Syrup, Plum Purée, Sugar, Raspberry Puree, Gelling Agent (Pectin), Acid (Citric Acid), Acidity Regulator (Sodium Citrates, Thiamin (B3)), Colour (Anthocyanins), Preservative (Potassium Sorbate), Flavouring) (23%)
- Plum and Raspberry Jam [Glucose-Fructose Syrup, Plum Purée, Sugar, Raspberry Puree, Gelling Agent (Pectin), Acid (Citric Acid), Acidity Regulator (Sodium Citrates, Thiamin (B3)), Colour (Anthocyanins), Preservative (Potassium Sorbate), Flavouring] (23%)
- Plum and Raspberry Jam [23%] (Glucose-Fructose Syrup, Plum Purée, Sugar, Raspberry Puree, Gelling Agent (Pectin), Acid (Citric Acid), Acidity Regulator (Sodium Citrates, Thiamin (B3)), Colour (Anthocyanins), Preservative (Potassium Sorbate), Flavouring)
- Plum and Raspberry Jam [23%] [Glucose-Fructose Syrup, Plum Purée, Sugar, Raspberry Puree, Gelling Agent (Pectin), Acid (Citric Acid), Acidity Regulator (Sodium Citrates, Thiamin (B3)), Colour (Anthocyanins), Preservative (Potassium Sorbate), Flavouring]
- Plum and Raspberry Jam (23%) (Glucose-Fructose Syrup, Plum Purée, Sugar, Raspberry Puree, Gelling Agent (Pectin), Acid (Citric Acid), Acidity Regulator (Sodium Citrates, Thiamin (B3)), Colour (Anthocyanins), Preservative (Potassium Sorbate), Flavouring)
- Plum and Raspberry Jam (23%) [Glucose-Fructose Syrup, Plum Purée, Sugar, Raspberry Puree, Gelling Agent (Pectin), Acid (Citric Acid), Acidity Regulator (Sodium Citrates, Thiamin (B3)), Colour (Anthocyanins), Preservative (Potassium Sorbate), Flavouring]

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Like this perhaps? `^([^][()]+)(\(.*?\)|\[.*?])\h*\[([^][]*)\]` https://regex101.com/r/mSWCdf/1

Comment: So the trailing `[23%]` is optional (it doesn't always exist in the input)?  For tasks like these, it is often best to provide 3 to 5 different sample strings that represent reasonable fringe cases, then provide your exact desired output for said sample strings.  This way you have best chance of receiving refined and accurate answers and whistle-blowers (such as myself) can clearly differentiate correct from incorrect answers.

Comment: @mickmackusa I've added a few different possible cases as examples of the data to the example at https://regex101.com/r/RzUs8E/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird this match is too greedy, it's getting the prepending text outside of any bracket.

Comment: May have found a solution https://regex101.com/r/Snrhfy/1

Comment: A [mcve] is expected to clearly present the inputs and the desired outputs directly in the question body.  External links can die.  Comments can be deleted without a mark in the public history.  Your question should be [edit]ed again.

Comment: If that solution works for you, you can also recurse the entire pattern without the groups `\([^)(]*+(?:(?R)[^)(]*)*+\)|\[[^][]*+(?:(?R)[^)(]*)*+]` https://regex101.com/r/Vr01KI/1